# cc cv charger issue in maltab simulink li ion cell model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

CC CV charger have an issue with charging series connected cells, when initial soc is t different the at the end of charging 2 cells voltage drop? is this cc cv charger issue of cell model issue?

while testing 12 cells connected in series, why 2 cells voltage drop at the end of charge? while other 10 cells have constant voltage?